# show table in laravel v5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I just want to show data from table you can see at this image below:

`project_id` refers to project name in project table

`activity_id` refers to activity name in activity table

[image: image show table fields]

The result i want to show is same as this image:

[image: result i want to show at web page]

here is my code

```
<table id="list-Dopeople-report" class="table table-bordered responsive">
          <tr> 
          <th>project</th>           
             @foreach($examples as $key=>$value)
                 <th>{{activityIdToActivityNameConvert($value->activity->id)}}</th>
             @endforeach
             </tr>            
             @foreach($pros as $key=>$value)
             <tr>
                 <th>{{projectIdToProjectNameConvert($value->project->id)}}</th> 
            </tr>
             @endforeach
     </table>
```

But the result has became like to the following image:

[image: wrong result]

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider here:

1. for best practices, add the 'thead' and 'tbody' tags
2. in your second foreach, you keep using 'th', which is used for table headings. Use 'td' instead.

The main problem is you only iterate over the 'tr'-element, which will keep adding rows. You do not iterate over the 'td' elements, which will fill up the columns

```
<table id="list-Dopeople-report" class="table table-bordered responsive">
    <thead>      
        <tr> 
            <th>project</th>           
            @foreach($examples as $key=>$value)
                <th>{{activityIdToActivityNameConvert($value->activity->id)}}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    <!-- here you iterate over the rows, which is ok -->           
    @foreach($pros as $key=>$value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{projectIdToProjectNameConvert($value->project->id)}}</td> 
            <!-- you should also iterate over the columns -->
            @foreach($project->activities as $activity)
                <td>{{$activity->time}}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
     @endforeach
     </tbody>
 </table>
```